# how to use Angular ng-change on input to change json data

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an array like this:

```
var data = [{
    "chamberName": "Community App",
    "representativeEmail": "some@email.com",
    "primaryColor": "#325490",
}]
```

And an input on a form like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="chamberName" ng-change="" placeholder="Chamber Name">
```

I'd like to use ng-change to change the array value that matches the changing input value. I can't figure out how to get the input value though. I am thinking something like:

```
ng-change="data[0].chamberName = inputValue";
```

Any help would be great!

SIDE NOTE: You need to use $parent when using ng-include.

Comment: I think you're looking for [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) not [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Comment: You want to create binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ngModel`.

Why your original data in array?

If you need to edit only one instance it is simpler to use object and pass object's property to `ngModel`

```
<input .. data-ng-model="data.chamberName" .. />
```

Or if you are going to edit pool of objects, than you can surround it with `ngRepeat`

```
<fieldset data-ng-repeat="elm in data">
  <input .. data-ng-model="elm.chamberName" .. />
  ..
</fieldset>
```

Or if you still want to store your single object in array

```
<input .. data-ng-model="data[0].chamberName" .. />
```

Comment: Do you have an example of ng-model?

Comment: What do you mean? I've wrote you three examples.

Comment: I got it now. I didn't understand that the ng-model="data[0].chamberName" was a binding type deal.